# JSP Page HttpServletRequest getAttribute Typecasting

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

Any ideas on the correct method of typecasting an Object out of a getAttribute request from a JSP page HttpServletRequest?

I have googled but it seems that the common solution is just sticking suppresswarnings in your code... Something I would very much like to avoid.

I currently have:

```
HashMap<String, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>> accounts = (HashMap<String, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>>)request.getAttribute("accounts");
```

And the complier is giving me this warning:
Unchecked cast from Object to HashMap

Thanks in Advance!!

MB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using JSTL tags to iterate over the collection, this allowed for an elegant solution not requiring suppression of unchecked warnings.

Comment: I bet you're talking about JSTL. That's indeed the right approach.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, either you need to cast or suppress the warning. In case you decide to suppress the warning, I recommend you to put a comment, too.

Similar [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509076/how-do-i-address-unchecked-cast-warnings), and [another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1129795/what-is-suppresswarnings-unchecked-in-java).