# Warning cloning ArrayList in Java

Tags: java, object, arraylist, clone, suppress-warnings

```
public void addProductList(ArrayList<ViewOrderProduct> globalOrderProductList) {

    this.productOrderList =  (ArrayList<ViewOrderProduct>)globalOrderProductList.clone();
}
```

This gives me the warning:

> Type safety: Unchecked cast from Object to ArrayList

I know that I can simply solve the problem adding `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")`.

But I want understand the problem. I can be sure that all goes good if I add the suppressWarnings? Is there another solution for this warning?

Comment: It is just a warning for you, because he can't verify at runtime that only `ViewOrderProduct` objects are in your cloned list.

Comment: You don't really want to use `clone` method...

Comment: @ThomasJungblut Nope, `clone()` returns an `Object`, so the warning is correct and has nothing to do with type erasure or the like.

Comment: @Neet you better reread the definition of an `Unchecked cast` ;)

Comment: Related about `clone` method and cloning/copying: http://stackoverflow.com/q/2326758/1065197, http://stackoverflow.com/q/2156120/1065197. Now, your problem is about the warning, related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/9499908/1065197

Comment: @ThomasJungblut ... *cough* ... yes, you're right. My fault^^

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`clone()` returns `Object` by default, the correct way to clone an `ArrayList` is to use the appropriate constructor:

```
this.productOrderList =  new ArrayList<ViewOrderProduct>(globalOrderProductList);
```

Edit: The preferred way is to use the appropriate constructor, and both methods only return a shallow copy anyways.

Edit: And there's no other way I'm aware of, to remove the warning using `clone()` without a `SuppressWarning`.

Comment: That will give you a shallow copy, not a in-depth copy. This, of course, depends on OP's needs.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza `clone()` on `ArrayList` also returns a shallow copy.

Comment: Refer to links I posted in OP's question about usage of `clone` method.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza well, the OP should skip the whole clone thing. Using the ctor is the preferred way anyways.

Comment: In short, yes. But the question itself is about using `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")`.

Comment: The only operation made over the globalOrderProductList is a .clear(), so I suppose I don't need a deep copy

Answer (score 0):

arraylist is wrapper over Object[], anything inside stored as Object, it does not matter what constructor is used result will be same.

as stated above, to evoid warning you shoud use constructor public ArrayList(Collection c) {}

eg new ArrayList(globalOrderProductList);

this will return copy of content without warnings.