# Generics and static methods

Tags: java, generics, static-methods

I have this static method

```
public static List<? extends A> myMethod(List<? extends A> a) {
  // …
}
```

which I'm calling using

```
List<A> oldAList;
List<A> newAList = (List<A>) MyClass.myMethod(oldAList);
```

This gives a warning because of the unchecked cast to `List<A>`. Is there any way of avoiding the cast?

Comment: What is oldAList defined as? newAList? The point of generics is to avoid casting, but you'll need to provide a bit more detail.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to define the type returned matches the argument (and extends A)

```
public static <T extends A> List<T> myMethod(List<T> a) {
    // …
}
```

Then you can write

```
List<E> list1 = .... some list ....
List<E> list2 = myMethod(list1); // assuming you have an import static or it's in the same class.
```

or

```
List<E> list2 = SomeClass.myMethod(list1);
```

Comment: It may be a bit nit-picky, but you you have a syntax error in your usage with list1 =

Answer (score 0):

You are casting it to the parent `A`, if you want to avoid that then change your return type for `myMethod`:

```
public static List<T> myMethod(List<T> a) {
  // …
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you define:

```
public static <T extends A> List<T> myMethod(List<T> a) {
// …
}
```

then you can call:

List =  MyClass.myMethod(List a){}

it is generic method, is`nt it?

Jirka

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can avoid the cast with static methods:

```
public class MyClass {
    public static List<? extends A> myMethod(List<? extends A> a) {
        return a;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List newList = new ArrayList<A>();
        List<?> newList2 = new ArrayList<A>();
        List<B> oldList = new ArrayList<B>();

        newList = MyClass.myMethod(oldList);
        newList2 = MyClass.myMethod(oldList);
    }
}
```

In the code above, B extends A. When newList variable is defined as List without generics or as List with wildcard type (List< ? >) cast is not necessary. On the other hand if you only want to get rid the warning you can use '***@SuppressWarning***' annotation. Check this link for more info [What is SuppressWarnings ("unchecked") in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1129795/what-is-suppresswarnings-unchecked-in-java)

Here is simple example for ***@SuppressWarnings ("unchecked")***:

```
public static List<? extends A> myMethod(List<? extends A> a) {
  // …
}

@SuppressWarnings ("unchecked")
newAList = (List<A>) MyClass.myMethod(oldAList);
```