# java - how to remove generic cast warning?

Tags: java, generics, casting

I have to use cls variable to some method.

```
Class<CommonResult<Cat>> cls = (Class<CommonResult<Cat>>) ((Class) CommonResult.class);
```

but, this code line displays this warnings.

- Class is a raw type. References to generic type Class should be parameterized
- Type safety: Unchecked cast from Class to

CommonResult is generic class.
I want to remove these warnings. what is the best modification to remove this warnings?
I want to know a method to fix it in code level not in annotation.

Comment: I don't believe the suggested duplicate was correct and I've reopened. Perhaps `@SuppressWarnings` is the only option, but I'd like to see someone explicitly state that this code can only be solved by that solution.

Comment: the method takes Class<T> class parameter. so I wanted to pass cls variable. thank you in advance.

Comment: If you do not have problem with the unchecked warning, just with the raw, you can use the `(Class<?>)` for the inner cast.

Answer (score 0):

I think that this question is your answer: [What is SuppressWarnings ("unchecked") in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1129795/what-is-suppresswarnings-unchecked-in-java), as well as your question is kind of an answer for that one :-)

As for your first 2 warnings listed - The "Class is a raw type" warning might stem from the fact that you first cast to `Class`. Is it necessary? The second item does not read like a warning. What should "parseGetGrantedPermission(String)" be? It looks more like your method that produced the warning.

Comment: I want to modify it in code level not in annotation. do you know another method to fix it?