# How do i get rid of these (unchecked call) warnings?

Tags: java, generics, javafx, warnings, unchecked

```
warning: [unchecked] unchecked call to setCellValueFactory(Callback<CellDataFeatures<S,T>,ObservableValue<T>>) as a member of the raw type TableColumn column1.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<String, State>("name"));   where S,T are type-variables:
    S extends Object declared in class TableColumn
    T extends Object declared in class TableColumn
```

code:

```
column1.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("name"));
```

---

```
warning: [unchecked] unchecked call to add(E) as a member of the raw type List
            transitionTable.getColumns().add(column1);
  where E is a type-variable:
    E extends Object declared in interface List
```

code:

```
transitionTable.getColumns().add(column1);
```

---

```
warning: [unchecked] unchecked call to setAll(Collection<? extends E>) as a member of the raw type ObservableList
        automatonSelection.getItems().setAll(automatonManager.getMachines());
  where E is a type-variable:
    E extends Object declared in interface ObservableList
```

code:

```
automatonSelection.getItems().setAll(automatonManager.getMachines());
```

automatonSelection is a ComboBox and getMachines() returns a LinkedList of the type Automaton

---

```
warning: [unchecked] unchecked call to addListener(ChangeListener<? super T>) as a member of the raw type ObservableValue
        automatonSelection.valueProperty().addListener((ObservableValue observable,
  where T is a type-variable:
    T extends Object declared in interface ObservableValue
```

code:

```
automatonSelection.valueProperty().addListener((ObservableValue observable,
            Object oldValue, Object newValue) -> {
        stateChanged();
    });
```

I tried to fix most of those warnings and managed to do so by adding generics, but I can't see how to fix those other 4 warnings.

Comment: @suppress annotation

Comment: Don't give things a `raw` type specify the type `ArrayList<>` vs. `ArrayList<String>`...

Comment: Have look http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1129795/what-is-suppresswarnings-unchecked-in-java  you got some better views

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Don't declare your `TableView`s and `TableColumn`s as raw types.

In other words, instead of

```
TableView personTable ;
TableColumn firstNameColumn ;
```

use

```
TableView<Person> personTable ;
TableColumn<Person, String> firstNameColumn ;
```

etc.

Don't suppress these warnings, they will help you debug problems.

Comment: i declared my columns exactly like this and still get the warning

Comment: Are you using Java 8? And for `transitionTable.getColumns().add(column1);` you cannot get the warning if `transitionTable` and `column1` are declared like this.

Comment: i managed to fix those warnings but the last 2 still remain,  can you maybe help out? especially the one with the listener

Comment: Can you show the declaration for `automatonSelection`? You should have `ComboBox<Something> automatonSelection ... ;` and `automatonSelection.valueProperty().addListener((ObservableValue<Something> observable, Something oldValue, Something newValue) -> ...);`