# Netbeans unchecked conversion for List<>

Tags: generics, netbeans-8

I'm learning Netbeans Platform and I'm in the process of following this tutorial:

[Link to Netbeans Tutorial](https://platform.netbeans.org/tutorials/nbm-crud.html#creating-entity)

I've reached the point of running the prototype but I'm getting the following warning in the output window:

```
warning: [options] bootstrap class path not set in conjunction with -source 1.6
warning: No processor claimed any of these annotations: javax.annotation.Generated
~/BDManager/CustomerViewer/src/org/shop/viewer/CustomerViewerTopComponent.java:53: warning: [unchecked] unchecked conversion
       List<Employee> resultList = query.getResultList();
  required: List<Employee>
  found:    List
3 warnings
```

My EntityManager is as follows:

```
EntityManager entityManager = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("CustomerLibraryPU").createEntityManager();
       Query query  = entityManager.createNamedQuery("Employee.findAll");

       List<Employee> resultList = query.getResultList();
       for (Employee c : resultList){
           jTextArea1.append(c.getFirstName()+" "+c.getLastName()+"\n");
       }
```

Referencing #4 in Designing the Interface in the tutorial, instead of the List being `List<Customer>`, my List is `List<Employee>` as the entity class is returning data from a table called employee in my database.

How do I get rid of this warning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That comes from the fact that `getResultList()` returns an untyped List (a raw type) which you are assigning to a typed List (where type parameter = Employee):

> java.util.List getResultList()
>
> Execute a SELECT query and return the query results as an untyped List.

More on generics and raw types [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2770692/1252603).

For suppressing that warning you can use `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")`. Check for example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1129795/what-is-suppresswarnings-unchecked-in-java) and in other related StackOverflow answers on how to do it.

Comment: @SuppressWarnings("unchecked") worked. Also thanks for the links.