# Why UnaryFunction<Object> can be casted to UnaryFunction<T>?

Tags: java, generics, effective-java

When I read ***Effective Java*** item 27, the type casting between `UnaryFunction<Object>` and `UnaryFunction<T>` confused me.

```
interface UnaryFunction<T> {
    T apply(T t);
}

public class Main {
    private static final UnaryFunction<Object>  IDENTITY = new UnaryFunction<Object>() {
        public Object apply(Object t) {
            return t;
        }
    };

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public static <T> UnaryFunction<T> identityFunction() {
        return  (UnaryFunction<T>) IDENTITY;
    }

    public static void main(String ... args) {
        UnaryFunction<A> identityA = Main.identityFunction();
        A a = identityA.apply(new A());
    }

}

class A {}
```

**Why `UnaryFunction<Object>` can be casted to `UnaryFunction<T>`?**

I know the generic type will be erased after complier. So `(UnaryFunction<T>) IDENTITY` will eventually be `(UnaryFunction<Object>) IDENTITY`, this will be working in Runtime.

But directly casting `UnaryFunction<Object>` to `UnaryFunction<A>` is not allowed by compiler.

```
UnaryFunction<A> identityA = (UnaryFunction<A>)IDENTITY;
//incompatible types: UnaryFunction<java.lang.Object> cannot be converted to UnaryFunction<A>
```

And there is no inheritance relationship between `UnaryFunction<Object>` and `UnaryFunction<T>`. So **why `UnaryFunction<Object>` can be casted to `UnaryFunction<T>`**?

Comment: Unrelated - "identity" doesn't have an "n" before the "d".

Comment: `T` could be `Object`. `A` definitely isn't.

Comment: @user2357112 it doesn't compile even if explicitly state A extends Object

Comment: @AlexanderKulyakhtin: Inheritance isn't enough. `A` isn't `Object`, so a `UnaryFunction<Object>` can't be a `UnaryFunction<A>`. `T` could actually be `Object`.

Comment: @user2357112 Do you mean T  **might be**  `Object`, so the compiler allow `UnaryFunction<Object>` cast to `UnaryFunction<T>` ?

Comment: I see now, thanks for the explanation

Comment: @RobinHan: Pretty much. If you put in a type bound like `T extends Integer`, so `T` definitely isn't `Object`, the compiler will reject the cast.

Comment: @user2357112 if I change the method definition to `public static <T extends Integer> UnaryFunction<T> identityFunction()` and `UnaryFunction<Integer> identityA = Main.identityFunction();`, the compile is still pass. So I don't think it's related to the bound.

Comment: @RobinHan: [The compilation fails.](http://ideone.com/cPTIzj) You must have screwed up your test.

Comment: @user2357112 Sorry my fault. The IDE doesn't mark it as red.

Comment: This is indeed a strange beast. [Compilation succeeds](http://ideone.com/KpWTmt) but when I inline method `identityFunction` it fails. This runs: `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Object cannot be cast to A`

Comment: `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")` is you telling the compiler "It may not look like it, but I promise I'm doing the right thing."  So it believes you.  It's your own fault if you lied to Java.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All generic types, without a bound (`... extends ...`, is considered `Object` due to type erasure. So this cast might be valid for some values of `T`. [`@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1129795/what-is-suppresswarnings-unchecked-in-java) tells the compiler you are doing the right thing so the warning is suppressed.

Casting to a specific type is problematic. Let's assume you are dealing with `List<Object>` which you cast to `List<A>` where `A` is a class. In this case list might have elements which are a supertype of `A` so this cast is unsound hence the compiler does not allow it. In case of the function (`UnaryFunction<Object>`) it is implied that this can return an Object. Say your code was `IDENTITY = t -> new Object();` in which case casting to `UnaryFunction<A>` would be unsound as it returns an `Object`. In the case it is `UnaryFunction<T>` there is some type `T` which satisfies the cast, that is, when `T` is an `Object`.

For some background reading on this see: [Liskov substitution principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle) which deals with subtyping of functions.