# am getting the Type mismatch: cannot convert from element type Object to String

Tags: java

I am storing the zero value at specific date.
I am  getting the exception at  `dur_call.put(value, "0")`

```
HashMap<String, String> dur_call = new HashMap<String, String>();
HashMap<String, String> brows_call = new HashMap<String, String>();
HashMap<String, String> brows_call_dst = new HashMap<String, String>();
HashMap<String, String> subs = new HashMap<String, String>();
HashMap<String, String> sub_dur = new HashMap<String, String>();
HashMap<String, String> act = new HashMap<String, String>();
HashMap<String, String> low_bal = new HashMap<String, String>();
HashMap<String, String> deact = new HashMap<String, String>();
HashMap<String, String> re_act = new HashMap<String, String>();

for (String value : datetime) {
    dur_call.put(value, "0");
    brows_call.put(value, "0");
    brows_call_dst.put(value, "0");
    subs.put(value, "0");
    sub_dur.put(value, "0");
    act.put(value, "0");
    low_bal.put(value, "0");
    deact.put(value, "0");
    re_act.put(value, "0");
}
```

Comment: Woah, that looks scary! Use [help] on more information about posting a question.

Comment: Please consider revising the code sample you posted in this question. As it currently stands, its formatting and scope make it hard for us to help you; here is a [great resource](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to get you started on that. And showing us what `datetime` is would also help a lot, since one of its elements is apparently not a String

Comment: Are you sure the error is one the `dur_call.put(value, "0");` line?  I don't think it is.

Answer (score 0):

I am sure that you get the error one line above, at

```
for (String value : datetime) {
```

That is the only place, where something wants to be converted into a `String`.

What is the type of variable `datetime` ? It seems to me that `datetime` is not an Iterable of Strings, which it should be (for that code to work).

Is your error an exception at runtime or a compiler error?

If it is an exception and `datetime` is an iterable of Strings, then you mixed up generics with some untyped Collection access - your compiler will probably give you a warning, where this occurs in your code - or you have annotated that place with a `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")`

(See also [What is SuppressWarnings (“unchecked”) in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1129795/2846138))

In this case try to make your whole code working without the unchecked warning *and* without the suppression of it.

If your error is a compiler error, you need to change the key of all your Maps to the type of the `datetime` iterable. `java.util.Date` maybe?