# unchecked call to ... as a member of a raw type

Tags: java, generics

I'm converting people's data into condensed form. So I have a bunch of interfaces:

```
public interface Brief {}
public interface Detail {}

public interface DetailToBriefConverter<T extends Detail, R extends Brief>  {
    R convert(T detail);
}
```

, a bunch of pojos:

```
public class StudentBrief implements Brief {...}
public class StudentDetail implements Detail {...}
public class EmployeeBrief implements Brief {...}
public class EmployeeDetail implements Detail {...}
```

and converters:

```
public class StudentDetailToBriefConverter implements DetailToBriefConverter<StudentDetail, StudentBrief> {
@Override
public StudentBrief convert(StudentDetail detail) {
    // logic here
    }
}
```

etc.

My main class looks roughly like this:

```
public class MainApp {

private Map<String, DetailToBriefConverter> map = ImmutableMap.<String, DetailToBriefConverter>builder()
        .put("employee", new EmployeeDetailToBriefConverter())
        .put("student", new StudentDetailToBriefConverter())
        .build();

public static void main(String[] args) {
    MainApp mainApp = new MainApp();
    String type = "employee"; // comes from the request actually
    Detail detail = new EmployeeDetail(); // comes from the request
    DetailToBriefConverter detailToBriefConverter = mainApp.map.get(type);
    detailToBriefConverter.convert(detail);
    }
}
```

And this works, but I get a warning `unchecked call to convert(T) as a member of a raw type DetailToBriefConverter`.

How can I get rid of this warning or do I have to live with it?

Comment: To get rid of the warning, you can either [suppress it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1129795/what-is-suppresswarnings-unchecked-in-java) or use the generic version of `DetailToBriefConverter<T, R>`.

Comment: The fact that the keys in the map are strings makes it impossible to do this in a way that's statically type-safe. The alternative to the raw type is to use unchecked casting, or to not make `DetailToBriefConverter` generic in the first place.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
DetailToBriefConverter detailToBriefConverter = mainApp.map.get(type);
```

`detailToBriefConverter` is a raw type: you aren't giving it a type parameter. Nor are you giving it one in the map.

Given that you are putting heterogeneous types into the map, the only type parameter you can use is `<?, ?>`:

```
DetailToBriefConverter<?, ?> detailToBriefConverter = mainApp.map.get(type);
```

(add it to the map declaration too)

But then you've got the problem that you can't invoke `detail` like this:

```
detailToBriefConverter.convert(detail);
```

because the type of the parameter is `?`, and you've got an `EmployeeDetail`, or whatever it is called.

Basically, what you are trying to do isn't type safe. It is possible that you can write the code in such a way that you don't actually get any runtime exceptions; but it's rather brittle.

---

What you really need is a type-safe heterogeneous container. Look it up in *Effective Java* or elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Change your method declaration to

```
public interface DetailToBriefConverter<T extends Detail, R extends Brief>  {
    Brief convert(Detail  detail);
}
```

And where you have declared DetailToBriefConverter, declare it is as DetailToBriefConverter

```
public class MainApp {

private Map<String, DetailToBriefConverter<? extends Detail, ? extends Brief>> map = ImmutableMap.<String, DetailToBriefConverter<? extends Detail, ? extends Brief>>builder()
        .put("employee", new EmployeeDetailToBriefConverter())
        .put("student", new StudentDetailToBriefConverter())
        .build();

public static void main(String[] args) {
    MainApp mainApp = new MainApp();
    String type = "employee"; // comes from the request actually
    Detail detail = new EmployeeDetail(); // comes from the request
    DetailToBriefConverter<? extends Detail, ? extends Brief> detailToBriefConverter = mainApp.map.get(type);
    detailToBriefConverter.convert(detail);
    }
}
```

Basically when you declare the class, you need to specify the  types, else you will get the raw types warning

Comment: If you're doing this, you may as well just remove the type parameters on `DetailToBriefConverter` altogether.

Comment: yeah, the whole idea was to have generic convert method, however it does remove the warning