# getClass() of a generic method parameter cast safety

Tags: java, generics

Is this cast safe?

```
private <T> void foo(T value) {
    final Class<T> aClass = (Class<T>) value.getClass();
}
```

Does a more elegant way exist to do this?

Is it possible to avoid unchecked cast warning?

Comment: It is safe. do a check before casting `value!=null`

Comment: It is not actually safe. The `Class` object returned will not be of type `T` but rather the *erasure* of `T` (or possibly a subtype). If `T` is generic then the returned `Class` object will not reflect the generic parameters. This is a mild case of heap pollution. In most cases it's benign, but most likely the *correct* approach would be to use a `Type` object instead of a `Class` object. Whether that's actually useful or not depends on what you're trying to accomplish here.

Answer (score 2):

You can suppress the compiler warning.  See [What is SuppressWarnings ("unchecked") in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1129795/3920048)

Compiler is warning you for a reason.  `value` can contain an object of some subtype of `T` and there are important differences between `Class<Parent>` and `Class<Child>`. In your case, you can see that you are not doing anything unsafe, but the compiler just follows the rules.

Imagine if the method was slightly different and there was a way to get another value of type `T`:

```
<T> void foo(T a, T b) {
    final Class<T> aClass = (Class<T>) a.getClass();

    // What can go wrong?  casting T to T
    T c = aClass.cast(b);
}

// but what if the two parameters are of different classes at runtime
foo(5, 5.5);   // ClassCastException!
```

Or what if we allow `Class<T>` to escape as a return value:

```
<T> Class<T> foo(T val) {
    final Class<T> aClass = (Class<T>) val.getClass();
    return aClass;
}

// uhoh is declared as Class<Number> but contains Class<Integer> at runtime
Class<Number> uhoh = foo(5);

// Ok to cast Double to Number but not to Integer
Number num = uhoh.cast(5.5);  // ClassCastException!
```

Comment: This answer is correct, but it misses the additional issues that generic types throw into the mix. `foo(new ArrayList<String>())` will return a value with the compile-time type of `Class<ArrayList<String>>` even though that type is impossible at runtime: the actual class object at runtime would be `Class<ArrayList>` for the corresponding raw type.