# How to avoid using @SuppressWarnings for casting a List

Tags: java, generics

I have the below code which casts a List object type, and I want to avoid using the `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")` annotation, but I do not want to turn it off in IDE settings as I realise the importance of it.

How would I rewrite the below so I can remove the annotation and the IDE doesnt highlight an unchecked cast warning?

I tried replacing the `CaseData` with a `?` element type, but I need to state `CaseData` for code later in the class.

I've looked at popular questions such as this: 
[What is SuppressWarnings ("unchecked") in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1129795/what-is-suppresswarnings-unchecked-in-java)

```
@Override
protected void buildExcelDocument(Map<String, Object> model, Workbook workbook, HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    List<CaseData> cases = (List<CaseData>) model.get("cases");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to do exactly this without a warning. A cast to a generic type simply cannot be check during runtime, and the compiler will inform you about that. I think that it is often totally legitimate to suppress that warning, so I don't think you really *need* another solution.

But if you can, follow @KarolDowbecki's [suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59143021/452775), I think that is the best solution.

If you want to avoid `SuppressWarning` anyway, the following are some work-arounds:

Perform the cast when when you are *using* the `CaseData` elements, instead of casting the whole list:

```
List<?> cases = (List<?>) model.get("cases");

// No warning here, since we're casting the element instead of the list
CaseData data = (CaseData) cases.get(0);
```

Copy the `cases` list and check all elements before hand:

```
// No warning here, since we're casting to List<?>
List<CaseData> cases = ((List<?>) model.get("cases")).stream()
// No warning here, since we're casting the elements instead of the list
    .map(d -> (CaseData) d).collect(toList());
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. Would need to add the cast to your first suggestion:  List<?> cases = (List<?>) model.get("cases"); I'll try these out

Comment: @Coder: Oh, I missed a cast there, sorry. Fixed.

Answer (score 1):

If `Map<String, Object>` contains mixed value types e.g. `cases => List<CaseData>` but `users => Set<User>` than you would have to replace the `Map<String, Object>` with a custom data class that will maintain the types:

```
class Model {
  List<CaseData> cases;
  Set<User> users;
}
```

and use it in the method signature:

```
void buildExcelDocument(Model model, ...) {
  List<CaseData> cases = model.getCases();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, there is no mixed value types

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to change your map as suggested by Karol, you could circumvent the issue by casting later and doing a proper check then:

```
List<?> cases = model.get("cases");

//later in the code...

if(cases.get(0) instanceof CaseData){
   CaseData case1 = (CaseData) cases.get(0);

   //do stuff
}
```