# Java required type <T> provided <?> generic compilation error

Tags: java, generics

How is Java unable to interpret this code:

```java
    private <T> Class<T> getClass(T object) {
       return object.getClass();
    }
```

I'm trying to visualise this and when I substitute in for an exmaple

```java
    private Class<String> getClass(String s) {
        return s.getClass();
    }
```

I get the same sort of error: `required type <String>` `provided type <? extends String>`. I've seen code that gets around this error by doing:

```java
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        Class<T> clazz = (Class<T>) object.getClass();
```

What does this mean? What am I not understanding about this generics problem?

Comment: i believe that this will help :) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1129795/what-is-suppresswarnings-unchecked-in-java

Comment: Due to type erasure Java cannot determine the type of the class at runtime. I usually get around this by adding the class as a parameter. Like this `private <T> void someMethod(T object, Class<T> class)`

Comment: If you have a `List<...> ex = new ArrayList<>()` and do `getClass` on it, then what type is the `Class`? As for the `Class<T>`, when you erase the generics information (aka when you evaluate this function at compile-time), what method would work for any possible input?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`getClass` follows some specific rules that are a bit unusual. The *declared* return type of Object::getClass is simply `Class<?>`, i.e. a class of some type. But as per [the docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#getClass--)

> The actual result type is `Class<? extends |X|>` where |X| is the
> erasure of the static type of the expression on which `getClass` is
> called.

The erasure for T in your example is simply Object, so the return is `Class<? extends Object>`. Everything extends Object, so that's the same as `Class<?>`.

When the parameter is the specific type String, the erasure is also String, and the result is `Class<? extends String>`.

[Oracle tutorial on type erasure](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html)

I guess what happens under the hood is that the compiler effectively "overrides" Object::getClass with a more specific return type. Child classes are allowed to return more specific types than their parents, but *not* less specific. Consider this valid code:

```
class Foo {
    public Class<? extends List<?>> foo() { return null; } 
}

class Bar extends Foo {
    @Override
    public Class<? extends ArrayList<?>> foo() { return null; }
}
```

Because of how this is implemented, `T obj; obj.getClass();` will return `Class<?>`, rather than what you're expecting which is `Class<? extends T>`.

In your case, the cast is safe.

Comment: This answer needs fixing - the type of `obj.getClass()` is in fact `Class<? extends T>` and not `Class<?>`. In other words, OP just needs to change their return type to `Class<? extends T>` instead of `Class<T>`, and in general `Class<X>` should always be written as `Class<? extends X>`, so that should never be a problem.

Comment: You end your answer with 'what you are expecting which is `Class<? extends T>`. No; it __is__ of type `Class<? extends T>`. OP's method sig demands a `Class<T>`. They just need to fix that part.

Comment: @rzwitserloot "*In other words, OP just needs to change their return type to Class<? extends T> instead of Class<T>*" No, you are wrong. https://ideone.com/GwJVdq

Comment: @rzwitserloot Not quite. "*The actual result type is Class<? extends |X|> where |X| is the **erasure of the static type** of the expression on which getClass is called.*". Since `T` is erased to Object we would need to change return type to `Class<? extends Object>` to make it compile (which is same as `Class<?>`), not to `Class<? extends T>`.

Answer (score 0):

As types are still erase you just have an `Object object`.

```
Class<?> type = object.getClass();
```

It is the other way around, one may use:

```
private <T> T getObject(Object object, Class<T> type) {
   return type.cast(object);
}
```

The above does a dynamic runtime cast. This might be useful:

```
private final Map<Class<?>, Object> singletonsByType = new HashMap<>();

public <T> void store(Class<T> type, T object) {
    singletonsByType.put(type, object);
}

public <S> S lookup(Class<S> type) {
    return type.cast(singletonsByType.get(type));
}
```

Answer (score -2):

You can salve that problem like this:

```
private <T> Class<T> getClass(T object) {
   return (Class<T>)object.getClass();
}
```

Comment: This generates a compiler warning for a reason.